# find: command not found error in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a bash script which will try to find all the `json` files in directories. When I try the command in terminal it works fine, but when execute the script I get error as `find: command not found`

```
test -d ./release && find ./release -type f -name '*.json' | while read file; do
 echo "****************************************"
 echo Processing file: $file
```

Not sure what mistake I am doing.

Comment: I suppose the environment during your script execution is different. Likely the search `PATH`. Perhaps a rc file that is being read at the start of it or the environment from which it has been executed?

Comment: Not related to your issue but you cannot reliably read the output of `find` unless your use `find -print0 | IFS= read -r -d '' pathname`, and then often `find -exec bash -c 'for file; do echo Processing file: "$file"; done' _ {} +` is a good enough option.

Comment: @OndrejK Sorry didn't understand what u mean by environment

Comment: Well ultimately [`envp`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) if the execution, but in plain English the environmental variable. In particular `PATH`. Could be some other difference, but that is a fairly plausible one. Depending on how have you executed it may have different value and make shell find or not the `find` executable.